# Undefined index errors on multiple line for filter and pagination PHP

Tags: php, error-handling, syntax-error, isset

```
$cate = $_REQUEST['cate'];
$fromdate = $_REQUEST['from'];
$to = $_REQUEST['to'];
$ascend = $_REQUEST['ascend'];
```

Notice: Undefined index: cate in 
Notice: Undefined index: from in 
Notice: Undefined index: to in 
Notice: Undefined index: ascend in

```
$limit = 10;            
$page = $_GET['page'];
if($page) 
$start = ($page - 1) * $limit;      
else
$start = 0;
```

Notice: Undefined index: on $page = $_GET['page'];

**Getting these notice but sometimes it disappears. Any thing wrong with it ?.**
**Top portion solved**

Now getting Undefined variable for following lines

```
if ($cate!='')

if ($fromdate !='' && $to!=''){

if ($ascend!=''){
```

Undefined variable: cate
 Undefined variable: fromdate
Undefined variable: ascend

Comment: You need to check if the index exists with `isset($_GET['page'])`, always.

Answer (score 0):

try `isset($_REQUEST['your_var_name'])`

It seems that sometimes you have those params set and sometimes it is not set(you do not have pass those params).You need to check if it is set or not for every `$_GET` and `$_POST` variable

e.g

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['cate'])) {
  $cate = $_REQUEST['cate'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just print the entire print_r($_GET) and print_r($_REQUEST) array and see the index cate, from, to and ascend are available.

Answer (score 0):

`$_REQUEST` is a combination of `$_POST` and `$_GET`.
For instance, `$_REQUEST['cate']` is set only if you have in url e.g. `index.php?cate=X` or you have sent your POST form containing input with name `cate`. So whenever you don't have it in URL or in form this variable is undefinied, that's why you got your notice. It's just a notice, so you can either hide it by using `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE)` or check if that variable has been initiated by `isset()`.